# What are the damage types?

Tags: command-and-conquer-red-alert

In the manuals, certain units are stated to be "effective" vs other units, e.g. rifle infantry effective against other infantry, light tank effective against light vehicles, but what does this mean in practice? X% more damage?

The rules.ini doesn't help either; it only mentions what weapons each unit uses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is there in rules.ini.

For example if you look up the section on mammoth tank you will see its primary weapon is 120mm. Now you go down to the weapon section, you will see the warhead of 120mm is AP, then down to the warhead section you will see this line
Verses=30%,75%,75%,100%,50%
which means the AP warhead (cannon type weapons) deals 30% damage to non armor (infantry), 75% to wood buildings and light armor, 100% to heavy armor, and 50% to concrete. That is why the mammoth tank seems so powerful against tanks but having issues against in infantry with much less hp.

Now look at Tanya's Colt45. It has a HollowPoint warhead (same as sniper) which has Verses=100%,5%,5%,5%,5%, therefore it is a very powerful weapon against infantry but practically can't do much with anything else. I mean it is even worse than E1's M1Carbine which buttom out at 25%.

Comment: The warhead types are: SA (small arms), HE (high explosive), AP (armor piercing), Fire, HollowPoint, Super, Organic and Nuke.

Answer (score 1):

It literally means they're more effective.

I think it's more about how much damage that weapon can do vs a certain unit rather than doing X% more damage.  I'm not sure if you noticed, but you can see your units actually miss their target with any weapon.  Next time you can, deploy some RPG troops against some riflemen and see how it works out.

In the simplest terms, it's because infantry and grenadiers *are only effective* towards other infantry troops.  RPG troops get destroyed by infantry and grenadiers because they're not meant to counter infantry - they're meant to counter vehicles.

This list can go on, but simply put, it really does just mean that the unit is most effective, and most practical when used against certain units.